# A cross-language Java/Beanshell way to check for void and null

Tags: java, beanshell

In BeanShell variables can be `null` or `void`. Is there a way to test for both (or at least `void`) using code which would work (unmodified, i.e. copied/pasted) in both BeanShell and Java? Something like: `SomeUtilityClass.isNullOrVoid(...)`.

I work with complex BeanShell scripts and being able to copy/paste code from a Java IDE into a script helps a lot with my productivity and the code quality (yes, that means I'm not using scripting features of BSH). The only issue is testing for `void` which forces me to manually adjust each script afterwards.

Issues with `void`:

- A check for `null` doesn't catch `void`:

`String foo; System.out.println("is null: "+ (foo == null));`

prints `is null: false`, which leads to code like `if (var != void && var != null) { ... }` which doesn't work in Java (and declaring `void` as a constant is impossible as it's a reserved word)

- `bsh.NameSpace` doesn't have a method to check for `void` and `getVariable(...)` returns `void`:

`String foo; System.out.println("variable: "+ this.namespace.getVariable("foo"));`

prints `variable: void` so we're back to square one. Even if there was a method to do that there (let's say I would write a custom NameSpace subclass with an appropriate method and `setNameSpace(...)` it) would need to be a way to invoke it in cross-environment way (see next point).

- writing a custom helper class with method like `isNull(Object bshNameSpace, String varName, Object var)` seems to be impossible.

A helper method like this:

```
public class Helper {
  public static boolean isNullOrVoid(This bshThis, String name) throws Exception {
    Primitive p = (Primitive) bshThis.getNameSpace().getVariable(name);
    return p == Primitive.NULL || p == Primitive.VOID;
  }
}
```

works just fine from BeanShell but there's no way (I know of) to rework it to work in Java (using reflection or otherwise) as it needs to work with method variables not instance fields. An alternative (clunky) version:

```
  public static boolean isNullOrVoid(Object bshThis, String name, Object var) throws Exception {
    if (!(bshThis instanceof This)) {
      return var == null;
    }
    Primitive p = (Primitive) ((This)bshThis).getNameSpace().getVariable(name);
    return p == Primitive.NULL || p == Primitive.VOID;
  }
```

works from Java but not BeanShell if the third parameter is *Undefined argument*.

- declaring a custom BSH command isn't an option either.

Even if the helper method is defined in the script itself it explodes exactly the same way with an *Undefined argument* exception:

```
public boolean isNullOrVoid(Object var) {
    return var == null || var == void;
}
String foo;
System.out.println(isNullOrVoid(foo));
```

Comment: Exactly what version of Beanshell are you using because I have tried your code examples and I do not see anything returning "void". Heck, "void" is not even a type in Java. It would somehow made sense if it would return "Void", but that is not case either.

Answer (score 3):

I can't make comments as I am relatively new here. I do apologize for this, as I would prefer to state the following as a comment.

I do question the premise of what you are trying to do. BeanShell is weak-typed which is why you need void. I could say `print(x);` and in this script x is void. Java is strong-typed and this code would not compile (assuming all the class/method code is in place, obviously). This means if you are pasting pure Java code into BeanShell then you should never encounter a need for void.

But if you insist, you could try fooling with the eval() command. The shared method would look like:

```
boolean isNullOrVoid(Object o) {
 return eval("o == void") || o == null;
}
```

This is fine for BeanShell, but now you have to implement the eval() command in your Java code, but because (as mentioned previously) there is no concept of void, then it should always return false.

PS void check should come before null check.